# Проблема с регулярным выражением для поиска списка

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть такой набор данных
"AB4g343434","AB34434h3434","AB343e43"
минимум будет одна, максимум не ограничен

вот такой регуляркой получается вытянуть одну запись, когда она одна:

```
'.*\("AB[a-z0-9]*"\)'
```

Как ее адаптировать под несколько таких разделенных запятыми, как указано в начале?

Comment: а bash и linux какое отношение имеют к вопросу?

Comment: Из вашего текста не очень понятен смысл вопроса, что и в чем ищется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/"(AB[a-z0-9]*)"/g
```

[**Демо и описание**](https://www.regex101.com/r/wO2oV9/1)